# Cython ImportError: ./h_f.so: undefined symbol: _ZN9haystack27featureD1Ev caused by Operation only allowed in c++ error from new feature()

Tags: python, c++, cython, importerror

I have read the relevant posts on the site for a whole day. But seems like this is an general error caused by different reasons. So I still post my question here. Any comments would be appreciated!!!

I was trying to wrap a c++ code which with one h_feature.h and one h_feature.cpp file with only one h_f.pyx file. Below is my h_f.pyx file:

```
from libcpp cimport bool
cdef extern from "h_feature.h" namespace "h2":

    cdef cppclass feature:
        feature() except +
        feature(char* modelDir, bool) except +
        bool load_feature_extractor(char* modelDir, bool)


    cdef cppclass Image:     # this is a struct in .h file, but i write it as class in pyx file here
        pass


cdef class PyImage:
    cdef Image* image

cdef class PyFeature:
    cdef feature* c_feature
    def __cinit__(self, bytes modelDir, bint useGPU = 0):
        self.c_feature = new feature(modelDir, useGPU)
    def Pyload_feature_extractor(self, bytes modelDir, bint useGPU = 0):
        return self.c_feature.load_feature_extractor(modelDir, useGPU)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.c_feature
```

Below is my setup.py:

```
    from distutils.core import setup, Extension
    from Cython.Build import cythonize

    compile_args = ['-g', '-std=c++11']
    setup(ext_modules = cythonize(Extension(
       "h_f",                                # the extension name
       sources=["h_f.pyx", "h_feature.cpp"], # the Cython source and
       extra_compile_args=compile_args,               
       language="c++",                        # generate and compile C++ code
  )))
```

Below is the warning during compile:

```
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -
    fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 
    -c h_feature.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/h_feature.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wstrict-prototypes' is 
    valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
    In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:121:0,
             from h_feature.cpp:21:
    hashtag2.cpp: In function 'PyObject* newarrayobject(PyTypeObject*, 
    Py_ssize_t, arraydescr*)':
    /usr/include/python2.7/pyerrors.h:220:74: warning: deprecated 
    conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
    #define PyErr_BadInternalCall() _PyErr_BadInternalCall(__FILE__, __LINE__)
                                                                      ^
    h_feature.cpp:959:9: note: in expansion of macro 
    'PyErr_BadInternalCall'
     PyErr_BadInternalCall();
     ^
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -
    fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 
    -c h_feature.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-
    2.7/h_feature.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wstrict-prototypes' is 
    valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
    In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:121:0,
             from h_feature.cpp:21:
    h_feature.cpp: In function 'PyObject* 
    newarrayobject(PyTypeObject*, Py_ssize_t, arraydescr*)':
    /usr/include/python2.7/pyerrors.h:220:74: warning: deprecated 
    conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
    #define PyErr_BadInternalCall() _PyErr_BadInternalCall(__FILE__, __LINE__)
                                                                      ^
    h_feature.cpp:959:9: note: in expansion of macro 
    'PyErr_BadInternalCall'
     PyErr_BadInternalCall();
     ^
    c++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-
    Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -
    fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -
    fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-
    security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/hashtag2.o build/temp.linux-
    x86_64-2.7/haystack2_feature.o -o 
    /root/h_feature/project/src/feature_wrapper/h_feature.so
```

Based on the comment, i add my c_feature.h below:

```
namespace h2 {

    typedef unsigned char pixel_type;


    struct Image;
    class feature_impl;

    class DllExport feature
    {
    public:

    feature();
    feature(const char* modelDir, bool useGPU = false);               
    ~feature();

    /*-------------------------------------------------------
    Method to load feature extractor

   Input: modelDir           model directory (...model/)
   */
    bool load_feature_extractor(const char* modelDir, bool useGPU = false);
   }

   struct Image {
          Image() { }
          Image(const Image& i) : width(i.width), height(i.height), bytes_per_row(i.bytes_per_row), pixels(i.pixels) { }
          Image(pixel_type* p, int w, int h, int bpr) : width(w), height(h), bytes_per_row(bpr), pixels(p) { }

          int width,height,bytes_per_row;
          pixel_type* pixels;
    };
    }
```

h_feature.cpp below:

```
namespace h2 {

    typedef std::mutex Mutex;

    // use the Lock primitive to acquire a given mutex for the object's lifetime. 
    // the mutex is released when the object is destroyed, typically when it goes
   // out of scope.

  class Lock {
      public:
          Lock(Mutex& _m) : m(_m) { m.lock(); }
          ~Lock() { m.unlock(); }

      private:
          Mutex& m;

          // don't allow copying or NULL constructor
          Lock();                         // unimplemented
          Lock(const Lock&);              // unimplemented
          Lock& operator=(const Lock&);   // unimplemented
    };

    // for now, use a heavyweight mutex to prevent concurrency issues in the API.
    // that is, all API calls must acquire the mutex and hold it for the entire call.
   static Mutex threadMutex;


  class feature_impl
  {
    // the base class for feature. threadMutex is used in this class. ommitted all implementation of this class.
   }

   feature::feature() : fi(new feature_impl)
  {
     }

   feature::feature(const char* modelDir, bool useGPU) : fi(new feature_impl)
  {
      fi->load_feat_extractor(modelDir, useGPU);
  }

  feature::~feature()
  {
    if(fi != NULL)  delete fi;
  }

  bool feature::load_feature_extractor(const char* modelDir, bool useGPU)
  {
      return fi->load_feat_extractor(std::string(modelDir), useGPU);
  }


  }; // namespace h2
```

Comment: The important details are probably in h_feature.cpp

Comment: Without seeing your h_feature.h and h_feature.cpp I would bet that you declare the destructor in h-file and don't implement it in the cpp-file

Comment: hi i have add my .h file and explained the .cpp file. Would you pls shed more light? thanks~!

Comment: Please add also cpp-file, without it is impossible to tell. Feel free to minimize your example

Comment: hi cpp file added. let me know if this is ok~

Comment: I deleted my (wrong) answer suggesting that the problem was because the files were both called "h_feature" and so the Cython file was blocking the C++ file. It was a bit of a guess but OP suggests it isn't the problem and that it shows the same error with renamed files.

Comment: @AllieYang Don't have time to test it currently, but one thing that catches my eye is an `#endif` at the end of your file. You aren't accidentally excluding your whole c++ file with the preprocessor?

Comment: hi hmm you can't test it coz i removed some code for the baseclass of 'feature'. The original cpp and h files are definitely ok. It is only when i wrap it with the pyx, i think i didn't wrap correctly in .pyx file. Maybe shed more light on where i wrapped not right? thanks!

Comment: for example, is it ok i just put 'bytes' to replace the 'char*' in the c++? im wondering if this is an error~

Comment: You should provide a working example. There are a lot of errors in the current state.

Comment: From the mangling of the names it looks like you are compiling with gcc. But gcc would not compile your h_feature.cpp without flag `-std=c++11` (mutex) which your setup.py is lacking.  I think that all symbols from `h_feature.cpp` are unresolved in your resulting shared library (`nm xxx.so`), this destructor is just the first symbol the dynamic linker tries to find. So I would say  @DavidW was probably right: in your log we see how `h_feature.cpp` is compiled and this obviously a product from cython. I was not fast enough to up-vote though:(

Comment: i just compiled with the updated setup.py but still same error. I tried compile manually with 'cython h_f.pyx' and it give me error of  ' Operation only allowed in c++', arrow pointing to the 'new feature(modelDir, useGPU)'... i think maybe i was wrong at here. But i do follow the Cython tutorial...any ideals pls?

Comment: What you are compiling is not the project you gave us. In the given cpp/h there are a lot of errors. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, follow it.  Start from the scratch,take information you gave us and try to build it. Did it work? If not, fix it and update your question. Repeat until everything works. Only then use @HandleName to contact people, so they get notified, when you made progress. I guess everyone did the same mistake at least once and posted examples  on SO which didn't work, so it is not a big deal, but you should not be wasting anybody's time with broken examples.

Comment: i fixed this error by add # distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = haystack2_feature.cpp on top of the .pyx file. New error with '_ZTINSt8ios_base7failureE'. I will open another post. thanks tho!